# Ionic5: Disabling ion-checkbox resulted in disabling ion-label when placed in same ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic5

I'm trying to only disable ion-checkbox but this resulted in disabling the ion-label placed in the same ion-item.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Using GPS</ion-label>
   <ion-checkbox slot="start" [(ngModel)]='reachedUsingBeacon' disabled="true"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

I tried to solve it by adding `pointer-events: auto;` but it didn't work.

```
ion-item {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the disabled property and use css to style it accordingly:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```